# How do I use JavaScript to call the AWS Textract service to upload a local photo for identification (without S3)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I want to call the `AWS Textract` service to identify the numbers in a local photo in JavaScript(without S3) and I get an error
`TypeError:Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined ': Error in' Client.send (command)`

I tried to find the correct sample in the AWS SDK for JavaScript V3 official documentation but couldn't find it.

I want to know how do I modify the code to call this service
This is my code

```
const {
  TextractClient,
  AnalyzeDocumentCommand
} = require("@aws-sdk/client-textract");
// Set the AWS region
const REGION = "us-east-2"; // The AWS Region. For example, "us-east-1".
var fs = require("fs");
var res;
var imagedata = fs.readFileSync('./1.png')
res = imagedata.toString('base64')
console.log("res2")
console.log(typeof(res))
// console.log(res)
const client = new TextractClient({ region: REGION });
const params = {
  Document : {
    Bytes: res
  }
}
console.log("params")
console.log(typeof(params))
// console.log(params)
const command = new AnalyzeDocumentCommand(params);
console.log("command")
console.log(typeof(command))
const run = async () => {
  // async/await.
  try {
    const data = await client.send(command);
    console.log(data)
    // process data.
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error");
    console.log(error)
    // error handling.
  } finally {
    // finally.
  }
};
run()
```